# Can't Import in Python 3.4.2 Shell

Tags: macos, python-3.x, python-idle

In the python shell, I can only import .py files after running a .py file with an import function in it, which means that I cannot import a file if it is right underneath the restart line of the shell. I took a screenshot of it(here i tried to import graphics.py and it IS in my python programs folder). Anyone knows what might be causing this problem!?

[image]

Comment: What Python installation are you using? That's not the standard Python shell; I've never seen `======== RESTART =======`.

Comment: i am using python 3.4.2 for mac and ActiveTcl8.5.17.0.298612-macosx10.5-i386-x86_64-threaded. Not sure if i answered your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Idle shell and the behavior you see is normal and expected.

When you restarted the shell by running a program, call it x.py, from the Idle editor, the 'current directory' was set to the directory, call it 'MyPrograms', containing x.py.  I presume 'My Programs' also contains graphics.py.  Hence the import works.  The fact that x.py did an import is irrelevant.

When you restarted the shell without running a program, the current directory is set to the installation directory, probably 'python34'.  Since graphics.py is then not on sys.path, the import fails.  The same would be true if you run the console interpreter in interactive mode without first running a program.  (I am not sure how this is done on a MAC.  On Windows, typing 'python' at a command prompt with python34 as the current directory does it.  So does using the 'Python command line' icon on the Start menu.)

Being able to restart the shell in either mode, without exiting and restarting at a command line, is an Idle feature that the console interpreter does not have.

Comment: i moved the graphics.py file into the python3.4 folder, the downloads folder, and even the utility folder but none of these worked

Comment: `import sys; sys.path` will show you directories searched for imports. `import os; os.path.abspath('.')` will show you the 'current directory', which corresponds to the initial '' entry in sys.path.